# PHP,CakePHPのサイトでレコメンド機能をつけたいのですが、

Tags: php, python

PHP,CakePHPでのサイトでレコメンド機能をつけるときに、レコメンドはpythonで書くと思いますが、どのような設計になりますか？
そもそも、PHPのサイトにレコメンドをつけようとするのが間違いですか？
PHPとpythonを共存させることは可能ですか？

Comment: レコメンドというのは「この記事を読んだ人はこんな記事も読んでいます」とか「あなたにオススメの記事はこちら」といった機能のことですよね。何故Pythonが必要と思われるのですか？

Comment: Pythonだと、ライブラリが豊富なのと数値計算に強いのでPHPでは難があると思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

普通に PHP で使えるレコメンドエンジンをお使いになったらいかがでしょうか？
[PHP+Mysqlで使えるレコメンドエンジンについて(8669)｜teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/8669)

> PHPとpythonを共存させることは可能ですか？

バッチで良いなら、python で計算して結果だけ db に保存し、php から読む。
リアルタイムなら、python をサーバとして起動して、php から通信する。
など、やり方は沢山ありますが、茨の道だと思います。